# Why does $some_array['an-undefined-key'] throw an error on Mac but not Wamp?

Tags: php, windows, macos, wamp

For some reason my Mac is displaying the error message "Undefined index: an-undefined-key" whereas on Windows with WAMP it gracefully ignores the exception.

Example of usage:

```
if ($some_array['an-undefined-key']) {
    // ...
}
```

Is there a PHP configuration which changes this behaviour?

I realise that I can do the following, but I would rather use the above technique if possible:

```
if (isset($some_array['an-undefined-key']) && $some_array['an-undefined-key']) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: you could do `if (!empty($some_array['an-undefined-key'])) {}` see http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: @fredrik this does indeed seem to work. In the past I encountered some issues with `empty` which is why I do not tend to use it, though I cannot remember what those problem(s) were :S

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to adjust the `error_reporting` and `display_errors` settings which sounds like they are different between your two different environments.

Here are links

[error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

[PHP ini_set - look at first example for display_errors](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the PHP on your Mac using the installed repo and your WAMP server is the php.ini, try editing your script and append the following lines to the top:

```
 ini_set('display_errors', '1');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

This should be on your scripts. If this is not the problem, then please comment back and I will change accordingly.

Comment: I tried doing this on both environments, but in both cases this didn't make any difference. One big difference is that Wamp is running a later version of PHP. I was unable to find any such changes though when searching the net.

Answer (score 0):

You should not add unnecessary line to your script as you will have to change them when you go live.

Edit you php.ini ( using the wampmanager menus so you get the correct file )

```
left click wampmanager -> PHP -> php.ini
```

Look for these parameters and change to these values

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

This one makes error show on the web page

```
display_errors = On
error_log = "c:/wamp/logs/php_error.log"
```

this one will make the errors log into the file specified by error_log even if they dont show on the screen

```
log_errors = On
```

WAMP comes with XDEBUG configured so you should now see big orange errors in the web page
Check the bottom of the php.ini file for this line. Numbers for versions may differ on your system

```
; XDEBUG Extension
zend_extension = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.X.Y/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.2.0-5.3-vc9.dll"
```